# What is the impact of replication factor using RepartitionByCassandraReplica?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, replication-factor

I have at my disposal 16 nodes and I am using Spark, Cassandra and Spark-Cassandra Connector(SCC). I want to evaluate the performance of this cluster from time perspective when a specific statistical test is implemented on some specific data. So, in one of my scenarios I kept the Spark nodes up to 16 and started adding nodes to the Cassandra ring. Every Cassandra node that is added, has already a Spark installation, and with the RepartitionByCassandraReplica(RBCR) I make sure that data locality is achieved. The only thing I changed was the replication factor.

The times were as follows:

```
number of Spark - Cassandra nodes | replication factor | Time
16 - 1                            |        1           | 1.883 min
16 - 2                            |        1           | 2.333 min
16 - 3                            |        3           | 0.933 min
16 - 4                            |        3           | 0.9 min 
...
```

My question is why in the 2nd case where I have 2 Cassandra nodes it takes more time than the 1st case with 1 node. I thought that the more Cassandra nodes, the more simultaneous reads. So does the replication factor play a role? If so, how?

I am using the RBCR, which means that when I fetch data from Cassandra, the SCC will ask the data from the node that is actually stored in. Therefore, I cannot see how the replication factor affects that.

**EDIT**

I think that if I had replication factor 2 for the case 16 - 2, I would get a lower time, something like 1.5, but that is something I cannot test right now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears to me that your testing is flawed. You need to have a one-to-one mapping of Spark workers/executors and Cassandra nodes.

As you already know, you can only achieve data locality when BOTH the Spark JVM and Cassandra JVM are co-located in the same operating system instance (OSI). In your environment, there is no guarantee that the scheduled worker/executor are on the same OSI as the Cassandra node. Cheers!

Comment: But, every Cassandra node I add has already Spark configured on it and therefore data locality is achieved because of RBCR. Also, in every case (of the above 4) the same data is distributed evenly i.e. on the 1st case in 1 node, in the 2nd case in 2 nodes, etc. So, the SCC will fetch the data from the nodes that is actually stored in. The "fetching of data" will be done on the first 1,2,3 or 4 nodes(depending on the case) and then the calculations will take place on all of the nodes(16).  However the times first go up for the 2 nodes and then down(and they stay down for the rest of the cases).

Comment: The Cassandra nodes I add are co-located with Spark. At least from an "instance perspective". They are on the same Openstack instance with the same IP address. However, I am suspecting that by "operating system instance (OSI)" maybe you mean something else?

Comment: It's not valid. It has to be one-to-one. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, but they are one-to-one, I just have more spark nodes. I have 16 openstack instances where every instance has 1 spark worker and cassandra. Do you just mean that being co-located is not enough, but also the number of spark and cassandra nodes must be the same? I know that during the spark calculations the locality is lost, but during the "fetching of data" the locality is maintained.

Comment: Is that what you mean? That being co-located is not enough, but also the number of Spark and Cassandra nodes must be the same? An answer would really be helpful even if you are not sure.

Comment: Yes, one-to-one means one Spark node to each C* node. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! So it is not enough just to be co-located but also the number must be the same! Apparently then, when we are talking about data locality, it does not only mean to fetch the data locally to spark(and cassandra does not stream the data) but also spark keep the data there as long as possible.